# How to map curl into java okhttp?

Tags: java, curl, okhttp

I have got a basic curl like below:

```
curl -X POST \
    'https://aogt.pl/auth/' \
    -H 'Authorization: Basic NGZjMjExNWQyYTZk' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    -d 'client_id=4fc2115'
```

When I run it in the console on e.g. Ubuntu everything work correctly, I get a good response. Now I would like to map this curl into the java code using okhttp. I write below code:

```
public class TestMain {
    private static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String data = "client_id=4fc2115";
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, data);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://aogt.pl/auth/")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic NGZjMjExNWQyYTZk")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response.body().string());
    }
}
```

The pom file look like:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
         <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The problem is that when I run this code I get "400 Bad Request" so this is problem with server. I wrong map above curl into the java code into the http. Probably the problem is in POST body, because it is not JSON, but what I need to change here, could you please tell me what is wrong? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request you want to send has content-type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
So creating the body as a JSON would not work.
You should try forming body in following way:

RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder().add("client_id", "id_value").build();

Answer (score 0):

`RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder() .add("client_id", "id_value");`
Hi hope you had resolved this problem.
Actually, if u want to send a request with 'form-body' instead of 'json', you can easily use this class: 'FormBody'. It inherits RequestBody.